# Why is an anonymous function on its own a syntax error in javascript?

Tags: javascript, parsing, syntax, grammar, anonymous-function

If I try to execute a script whose only source line is an object:

```
{prop:'value'}
```

it parses fine (in both V8 and UglifyJS). Similarly I can put a string or number on its own as source code and there is no syntax error reported.

However, both V8 and UglifyJS complain about this on its own:

```
function(){}
```

I get `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token (`.

Why does this break when the object in the first example is fine? Aren't functions just objects in javascript?

I realise declaring an anonymous function without executing it won't do anything; that's not the question. I want to know why it causes a parse error.

Comment: Well it's missing a function name as declaring a function follows the rule `function [name] () { [code] }` so the actual question could be: Why are there special circumstances where you can create an anonymous function?

Comment: An "anonymous function" is more correctly a function expression without the optional name (see [FunctionExpression](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-A.5)).

Comment: what's interesting just add some operator and this works :)
`!function(){};+function(){};`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From the ECMAScript spec, section 12.4 on expression statements:

> Note that an *ExpressionStatement* cannot start with an opening curly brace because that might make it ambiguous with a *Block*. Also, an ExpressionStatement cannot start with the `function` keyword because that might make it ambiguous with a *FunctionDeclaration*.

Although functions are just objects, remember that you can declare functions on their own without really making use of their objects in expressions. That's where the ambiguity lies. Granted, you can never declare an anonymous function on its own (as you won't be able to reference it anyway), but as I can't find anything in the spec that distinguishes between anonymous function and named function declarations, I suspect this applies to both.

In order to resolve the ambiguity you need to wrap it in parentheses, so it will always be treated as an expression:

```
(function(){})
```

Comment: You're right, wrapping in parentheses works. I fail to see how `function(){}` is ambiguous though. What else could it mean?

Comment: @Andrew—it would be ambiguous because it could be a function expression. Note that function declarations are processed before any code is executed, function expressions are processed after that when the code is executed.

Comment: @RobG You mean it could be a function declaration? How can it be - it has no name.

Comment: The compiler needs unambiguous rules for processing code that work generally (that is, everywhere in all cases). How would the compiler ever know the difference between a named function expression and a function declaration if either could appear anywhere? If you do that, you either get rid of declarations or expressions. Which don't you want? :-)

Comment: @RobG I see what you mean. If `function(){}` was legal then `function f(){}` could either be a FunctionExpression or FunctionDeclaration. I don't think I've ever seen a _named_ function expression in use.

Comment: They're useful for debugging, but have quirks in IE 8 and lower. They're handy for recursion for a function expression instead of arguments.callee, though I prefer the latter, see [Named function expressions demystified](http://kangax.github.com/nfe/).

Answer (score 5):

`{prop:'value'}` is not parsed as an object, just parsed as a block, which has a label `prop`.

You need `()` to enclose it to parsed as an expression.

`({prop: 'value'})` will be parsed as an object expression.

`(function(){})` will be parsed as a function expression.